# How can I do to avoid logout function deletes info about sessions

Tags: python, django

I want to identify navigator sessions, not users sessions.
I want  session_id to perdure even if they log in or logout, but logout functions deletes all the information about sessions, I don't want to delete nothing.

Comment: you can write your own logout view and logout function to not flush the session but just remove the `_auth_user_id` key from the session and replace the `request.user` with an empty `AnonymousUser()`. Look at `django.contrib.auth.logout`